Delphi Webservice server, como responder de forma inmediata
Tengo un WebService server desarrollado en Delphi XE2, funciona sin problemas
El problema es que lo consumen servidores corporativos que exigen que el webservice responda en menos de 5 segundos, lo cual no me da tiempo de hacer lo que tengo que hacer, asi que estoy buscando la forma de responder a la solicitud y despues hacer mi gestion
Es mas o menos asi lo que esta actualmente
function WebServiceGrabaInformacion(Info:string) : string
begin
   ValidaInformacion(Info);
   GrabaInfoEnBD(Info);
   Result := 'Informacion Recibida';
end;

OK, el response o respuesta se le envia al cliente cuando termina la funcion, y se envia Result
El problema es que la funcion ValidaInformacion puede llevarse hasta 60 segundos y la respuesta entonces se envia despues de esos 60 segundos.
Estoy buscando algo asi (que responda inmediatamente, y despues hacer lo que tengo que hacer)
function WebServiceGrabaInformacion(Info:string) : string
begin
   RespondeAlCliente('Informacion Recibida');
   ValidaInformacion(Info);
   GrabaInfoEnBD(Info);
end;

Entonces, como programo la funcion "RespondeAlCliente" ?
Gracias antemano
(Nueva Info)
Ya encontre que si es posible enviar la respuesta de forma anticipada, aqui esta la informacion, pero sigo sin entender que objeto es el que tiene el evento OnAction
https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Sending_the_Response
O sera que solo la version Sydney de Delphi tiene esa opcion ?

En la DocWiki ya no está disponible la documentación de XE2, que es una versión de hace 13 años, pero diría que la infraestructura no ha cambiado y podrías escribir un manejador para ese evento, de cualquier manera te va a quedar la tarea de realizar la acción posteriormente. La documentación que enlazas dice "If you are sure there is no more work to be done"...  Lo que yo haría es mantener una cola de tareas por realizar y tener uno o varios hilos secundarios que las realicen, con lo que en el método GrabarInformacion solo metería la Info a la cola y escribiría la respuesta.

Pues, es de suponer que el resultado de ValidaInformacion y GrabaInfoEnBD no afectan la respuesta que se da. Hay distintas formas de implementar esta cola. Lo primero que me viene a la mente es una TThreadQueue<string>, aunque tiene  el defecto que al bajar tu servicio se perdería lo que está  en cola en ese momento. Otra opción es grabarlo a una base de datos y que el proceso del hilo secundario vaya tirando de lo que está en la tabla.  También puedes lanzar estos hilos secundarios desde cada llamada a GrabaInformacion.

De lo que no hay forma es de responder y que la misma llamada se quede procesando después de haber respondido. Si respondes, la llamada termina, de una forma o de otra, y lo más simple es responder desde el método que ya tienes, con el resultado de la función.
